# Is there anyway to retrieve the version of a running file?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a python file that I modified without making a backup first. There is a screen session that is currently running the file. Is there any way to get the code that is in the running file back or am I SOL?

Comment: You're out of luck. Python compiles the file to byte code when you run the script, and that's the only thing in Python's memory.

Comment: Thank you, I figured as much but it was worth a shot. Feel free to write this as the answer.

Comment: If the interpreter has the source file open, then you can recover the source file through the file descriptor. I recovered a database I accidentally deleted using [Recover deleted file held open by Apache?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/58949) Also see [How to recover deleted file if it is still opened by some process?](https://superuser.com/q/283102/173513) In my case the program was a long running process, so the file handle to the database was still open.

Comment: @jww: Unfortunately, based on a quick test, the interpreter does not keep the file open.

Comment: @jww That might work if the file was deleted, but the question says it was modified. If the editor overwrites the file in place (rather than writing a new file and deleting the original), the open file descriptor will point to the modified file.